# Question on Spectral Mapping Theorem in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

[image]

[image]

I understand the whole proof except for the part which says:

> Factor $p(x)-\mu=c(x-x_1)\dots (x-x_n) $ [...]

I understand why I can factor $p(x)$ individually but why do I obtain $p(x)-\mu$ is also factorable?

Any help would be valuable! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p(x)$ is not constant, $p(x)-\mu$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $p(x)$, so it is also subject to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to post Comments, so I write an answer. 
In the middle of the quotation, the following sentence makes only sense to me with the $inverse$ of $p(T)-p(\lambda) I$:

"Then $p(\lambda)$ can not be in the resolvent set of $p(T)$, for then $q(T)(p(T)-p(\lambda) I)^{-1}$ would give a bounded inverse for $T-\lambda I$.

I hope this helps.